# How to add FreeImage.dll to C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have successfully added other .dll files to other C# project this way:

`Right click Reference > Add Reference > Browse > Double click the .dll file`

but Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 issues the following complaint:

`A reference to ...\dll\FreeImage.dll could not be added. 
Please make sure that the file is accessible, 
and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.`

I am using .NET Framework 3.5. I believe this is a 32bit dll (it downloaded with FreeImage3151Win32) so I changed the configuration of the project to x86.

What is the correct method to add FreeImage.dll to a C# project?

Comment: Is FreeImage.dll a .Net dll? Can you open it with ildasm, reflector or ilspy?

Comment: I guess (since this library also works on Linux) that the DLL exposes a C API.  If so, you need to use Interop to declare all the DLL exports, much as you would for the Win32 API.  Or find someone who's done it already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `wrapper` provided in the download. There are C# samples in the `\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\Samples` directory.

Comment: No, it is no longer in that directory.

Comment: I just tried downloading what seems to be the latest binary (3.15.3) and it's still in that directory for me. Where is it for you?

Comment: FreeImage3153.zip so I guess it's the same version :-/

Comment: Ah, my one is FreeImage3152Win32.zip (binary, not source code).

Comment: Actually, in the current release (3.15.4), have to build the project in FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs to produce the DLL for C#. Then you find it in FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\Library\bin\Release or Debug.

Answer (score 1):

The FreeImage.dll isn't a .Net dll. You need to write a wrapper in .Net which call the methods of the unmaged code. There is an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/freeimagecswrapper.aspx) but they also supply a .net wrapper in the binary distribution [here](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before with files downloaded from the Internet that are "blocked" by the file system.  Try going into the file's properties and clicking the "Unblock" button.

Comment: that's not the problem in this case

Answer (score 0):

In the current release (3.15.4), have to build the project in FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs to produce the DLL for C#. Then you find it in FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\Library\bin\Release or Debug.

Answer (score -3):

Save the file into the Bin folder and click Project > Add Reference > Browse > Double click the .dll file

[C# sharp helps link](http://bamaracoulibaly.blogspot.co.uk/)