# Add FreeImage .NET to solution

Tags: c#, dll, freeimage

I have followed the posts on this, but i am still not getting a few steps. I am new to C#, and that is probably the issue. I would love a little help (I have been banging on this all day).

I can open the FreeImage.NET solution (Win7 64 bit machine btw) in Visual Studio. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648347/how-to-add-freeimage-dll-to-c-sharp-project) says i need to Build it to get the C# dll. When i build it, i get hundreds of errors "type or namespace 'Name' could not be found".

Does it need the C++ DDL added first? I dragged and dropped it onto the solution, but still the errors.

Am i doing something simple and wrong?

Specifically what i am trying to do is add FreeImage to project in C# Visual Studio Express 2012.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: is that the exact error?

Comment: Also, why not just download the pre-build dll from : http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html then you dont have to worry about the build?

Comment: Is there anything else you were looking for?

Comment: @box86rowh: not sure what you mean. i looked at the page and unclear which you are suggesting to download.

Comment: I was referring to the DLL download linked on that page:  

FreeImage DLL
Binary distribution includes DLL, linkage LIB, header file, C++, C#, Delphi and VB6 wrappers, and examples.
 
Download FreeImage 3.15.4 [WIN32]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After downloading the version of FreeImage.NET , I opened the following VS2005 Solution File in VS2012.(Thats the only one I have)

> FreeImage3154\FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\FreeImage.NET.2005.sln

After upgrading the project and building it for the first time, I saw around 491 errors. If you open the references of the `UnitTest.2005` project, you will see that the `nunit.framework` assembly is missing. If you have nuget installed , in VS2012 you can

> Right Click references > Manage NuGet Packages > Search for NUnit and install it.

In the image below we see that the `nunit.framework` assembly is correctly linked.
[image]

After doing this there were only 50 errors remaining and they were all because the Xml Documentation file checks were enabled. You can disable this check as shown below in the `Library.2005` project.

Build again, and it should succeed.

**NOTE:** The [FreeImage website](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html) provides only a 32-bit version of the DLL, thus to use this DLL you will have to ensure that you set your project version to 32-bit. To obtain a 64-bit version of the FreeImage DLL you will have o download their source code project and manually do a 64-bit build as show in this [blog](http://www.sambeauvois.be/blog/2010/05/freeimage-and-x64-projects-yes-you-can/).

Comment: I had posted the thought that VS 2010 and VS 2012 are not listed as supported, but i deleted it as Romulus has stated he has VS 2012 and its worked for him.

Comment: @ZafKhan: Yes it worked fine in vs2012. I was surprised too. The point worth noting was that I had to set the workspace as a 32-bit version as I had downloaded a 32-bit version of FreeImage.dll. With both the FreeImage.dll and its wrapper i.e. FreeImageNET.dll in my build folder it worked fine.

Comment: Sounds like their site needs updating to the fact that VS2010 and VS2012 are supported.

Comment: Thanks, Romulus, your detailed instructions most appreciated, worked exactly as you say. I needed to search nunit in the web section of Manage NuGet packages, and install it. Seems I can now use the wrapper. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226743/access-pixels-in-a-16-bit-tiff/16288531#16288531) where Denver helps with the next steps.

Comment: Hello @DanG, Glad you managed to your resolve problems. I had faced the 32-bit issue too but I made a mistake of adding that information as a comment. See second comment, I have added it to the main post.